# Testacular: encountered a declaration exception

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have defined a empty module in angular.js:

```
angular.module('todoList', [], function () {

})
```

then I want test it, in my `conf.js`, I load these javascript:

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  // lib
  '../js/lib/angular.min.js',
  '../js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',

  // our app
  '../js/project.js',

  // test file
  "test/*.js"
];
```

Then I want test it in test file:

```
describe('My own function', function(){
    beforeEach(module('todoList'));
});
```

but this step tell me

`FAILED My own function encountered a declaration exception`

I don't understand why just a load module sentence would cause wrong

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including angular-mocks.js in your config file.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much! But why I need this file?

Comment: Mocks replace portions of code during testing to isolate each test. You use mocks by creating "stub" versions of inputs and responses. The angular-mocks file defines mock versions of angular's services necessary for testing.