# jasmine encountered a declaration exception

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Running Visual Studio I have the following jasmine test.

```
'use strict';

///<reference path="jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Scripts/angular.min.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Scripts/angular-mocks.js"/>
///<reference path="../application.js"/>

describe('StatusPage Tests', function () {
    describe('Application Functions', function () {
        var location;

        beforeEach(module("StatusApplication"));

        beforeEach(inject(function($location) {
            location = $location;
        }));

        it('DetermineRootUrl_Application_RootUrl', function () {
            var result = DetermineRootUrl(location);

            var expectedResult = 'https://localhost/OK59SP1/';
            expect(expectedResult).toBe(expectedResult);
        });
    });
});
```

the problem seems when I try and use a angular-mock function.
as soon as I include any of the beforeEach code blocks the test does not run and the only message I get back is "encountered a declaration exception"

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, any suggestions?
I checked the paths to the files referenced and they are correct.

Comment: Are you running the JavaScript tests in ReSharper? Have you tried looking at the browser's console to see if there is more detail on the error there?

Comment: Any news? Did you solve that issue?

Answer (score 4):

This happened for me in `jest` when I used `expect` directly inside `describe`. `expect` should be called inside `it` (or whatever alias it has like `xtest`, `test`)

```js
describe('a', () => {
   expect(1).toEqual(0); /// encountered a declaration exception

   it('b', () => {
      expect(1).toEqual(0); /// works fine
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this out: [Testacular: encountered a declaration exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739763/testacular-encountered-a-declaration-exception)

> Try including angular-mocks.js in your config file

Answer (score 1):

The references must be on top of the file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7003383/5409756). I recommend also to create a references file with all references included. This way you have only to include one file in all the tests. ([How to reference multiple files for javascript IntelliSense in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448119/how-to-reference-multiple-files-for-javascript-intellisense-in-vs2010))

This should work:

```js
///<reference path="jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Scripts/angular.min.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"/>
///<reference path="../../Scripts/angular-mocks.js"/>
///<reference path="../application.js"/>

'use strict';

describe('StatusPage Tests', function () {
    describe('Application Functions', function () {
        var location;

        beforeEach(module("StatusApplication"));

        beforeEach(inject(function($location) {
            location = $location;
        }));

        it('DetermineRootUrl_Application_RootUrl', function () {
            var result = DetermineRootUrl(location);

            var expectedResult = 'https://localhost/OK59SP1/';
            expect(expectedResult).toBe(expectedResult);
        });
    });
});
```